# position:fixed navbar takes margin attribute of another div

Tags: html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>

<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My portfolio</title>
        <style type="text/css">
        * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20000px;
}



h1 {

}

#headname {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: #356684; 

}

#calculator {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 500px;
    font-family:arial;
}

**#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #eee;
}**
ul {

}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;

}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 0 20px;

}

ul li a:hover {
    color: #627f91; 
}

**#bodie {
    margin-top:80px;
}**</style>
    </head>

<body>
<nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="headname">My portfolio</li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav id="navigation">
    <div id="bodie">
        <h1>Welcome to my portfolio</h1>

    </div id="bodie">
    </body>
</html>
```

I have a navigation bar position:fixed; at the top of my page, in a nav container with the id "navigation".
I have a little piece of text under there, in a seperate div, id'd "bodie", that I have given the attribute: margin-top:80px;. So it would be displayed under the navigation bar.

For some reason, the navigation bar gets this attribute as well. I don't get why. Could someone explain this to me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add `top: 0;` to the navigation with the fixed positioning.

Also, you don't include the id on the closing tag, so `</nav id="navigation">` should just be `</nav>`. This applies to the div tag too.

```css
 * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin-bottom: 20000px;
}



h1 {

}

#headname {
    font-size: 30px;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: #356684; 

}

#calculator {
    text-decoration: none;
    padding-right: 500px;
    font-family:arial;
}

#navigation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 60px;
    background-color: #eee;
    top: 0;
}

ul {

}

ul li {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;

}

ul li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: arial;
    color: #1e1e1e;
    padding: 0 20px;

}

ul li a:hover {
    color: #627f91; 
}

#bodie {
    margin-top:80px;
}
```

```html
<nav id="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li id="headname">My portfolio</li>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
</nav>

<div id="bodie">
<h1>Welcome to my portfolio</h1>
</div>
```